# Differences in print output/format

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python and trying to figure out why the following 2 lists generate different output formats

```
n=5  
mylist = "*" * n  
print(mylist)  
mylist = ["\*", "\*", "\*", "\*", "\*"]  
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
*****  
['\*', '\*', '\*', '\*', '\*']
```

Comment: Just realized that mylist = "*" * n probably does not generate a list

Comment: No it does not. It creates a string object made by concatenating ' *' + ' *' +.. n times. It's still a string object though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"*" * 5` gives you a string of length 5.

`["*"] * 5` gives you a list of five strings of length 1.

In both of these cases, the result has the same type as the "input," just five times longer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first variable is a string and the second is a list.

When you do "*" and multiply it by n you multiply that character n times and it returns a string.

The second one you declared as a list and is thus, printed as a list.

Answer (score 0):

In Python when using a multiplication operator (*) with a string this string is repeated according to the number, for example

```html
str = "-" * 6 # output : ------
```

NOTE : This operation returns a string and not a list

The second output is simply a list with elements and its output is as expected

I hope I have helped

Answer (score 0):

My output is

```
*****
['\\*', '\\*', '\\*', '\\*', '\\*']
```

Obviously,`"*" * n` is a string,`["\*", "\*", "\*", "\*", "\*"]` is a list. If you want to create a list, please set a list first.